# Почему был закрыт вопрос, который, как мне кажется, достаточно полно описан?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Считаю, что [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176043/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2) вопрос достаточно полно описан. Деталей не требуется. Комментариев нет.

Почему сообщество решило его закрыть?

Answer (score 2):

> вопрос достаточно полно описан

Учитывая, что его закрыли, то нет.

> Деталей не требуется

Требуется, раз закрыли.

> Комментариев нет. Почему сообщество решило его закрыть?

В причине вроде как всё указано было. Участникам не понятна суть вопроса. Посмотрите на свой вопрос со стороны и скажите, если бы вы не были в теме, возможно ли однозначно на него ответить в текущей формулировке?

---

> Да. Я использую SO как пул моих заметок и исследований. Иногда это полезно другим

Учитывая, что это самоответ, то можно было и подробнее вопрос и ответ расписать. SO, в первую очередь, не ваш личный блокнот.

Comment: Что в вопросе не ясного? Что такое теги не ясно?

Comment: @hedgehogues почему вы у меня спрашиваете? (: Можете у закрывашек в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) спросить.

Comment: Как человека в чат пригласить? Ни разу не пользовался

Comment: @hedgehogues как и в комментариях. Через @. Но если человека в чате не было больше месяца, то не получится =/

Comment: @hedgehogues если найти профиль StackExchange chat, то там есть кнопка "invite this user to". Например https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/175841/grundy слева внизу

Comment: @hedgehogues , вопрос был закрыт по сути потому что один из модераторов проголосовал за его закрытие. Если бы не его голос, то возможно по результатам проверки в очереди вопрос бы не закрыли. Но вообще соглашусь с Андреем - SO в первую очередь база знаний, а не чей-то личный блокнот. Вопрос лучше формулировать максимально полно - для вас возможно смысл вопроса очевиден, но это не значит что он понятен другим. К данному вопросу у меня претензий нет, но ваш подход использовать SO для заметок мне не нравится.

Comment: > если бы вы не были в теме, возможно ли однозначно на него ответить в текущей формулировке?

Применительно к данному вопросу, мне кажется что если человек настолько не в теме, то как его не переформулируй, это ему не поможет.